# I have a function that should print an array, but for some reason it does not work

Tags: c++, function

I think some problem happening when I send the array in function, but I'm not sure.

```
#include <iostream>

struct cell
{
    int value{0};
    bool checker{0}; // It's use in another case.
};

void printBoard(cell board[9][9])
{
    using namespace std;
    for (int line{0}; line < 9; ++line) {
        for (int column{0}; column < 9; ++line) {
            cout << board[line][column].value << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cell board[9][9];
    printBoard(board);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected to get:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

But it returns random numbers. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change inner `for` from

```
for (int column{0}; column < 9; ++line) {
```

to

```
for (int column{0}; column < 9; ++column) {
```

Comment: Totally unrelated to your answer, but since when can you initialize struct values to an initial value? Wouldn't he need to first create cells with specific values and only then it's guaranteed that he doesn't get garbage values?

Comment: @pr0f3ss  `int value{0};` default initializes each element to `0`

Comment: @Simon Just read about this feature, it has been added with C++11. Good to know

Comment: @pr0f3ss: [*default member initializer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) has been introduced in C++11

Answer (score 2):

You have typo in your indexes.

Using for range loop minimize those kind of typos:

```
void printBoard(const cell (&board)[9][9])
{
    for (const auto& rows : board) {
        for (const auto& c : rows) {
            std::cout << c.value << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```